# How wirte many rows of Dataset<string> in only single file txt with Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
I have a Dataset<String> and I need to write it in a txt file.

In this Dataset<String> I have three rows.

When I try, Spark writes three different files to the directory, I need to merge these lines into just a single string and then write.
```

my code :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIdI7.png)

```
input.write().mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).text("src/main/resources/avro/BVA_RET_20210618")
```

when use .show() [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9QaU.png)

on debug mod[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTLMU.png)

spark create this way:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1gA7.png)

I need the file with three rows together like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5uEu.png)

I need to merge  three rows in a single file.

Comment: Please add code and desired/actual output in the question itself(not as image)

Answer (score 1):

Just do a reparation before writing, obviously do this only when the data is very small.

```
df
   .coalesce(1)                              //or .repartition(1)
   .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
   .text("src/main/resources/avro/BVA_RET_20210618")
```